Expo 51 is crashing when using expo-file-system FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(...).downloadAsync();
The Expo 50 version works fine. However, after updating to Expo 51, the application terminates without any message.
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

// ...

const result = await FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
    uriHttps,
    uriFile,
).downloadAsync(); // This line causes the crash.

    "expo": "^51.0.14",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",

The application works fine on Android with Expo 51 and on iOS with Expo 50. However, it crashes on iOS with Expo 51.
Is there somebody who faced this issue?
I expect to see an error message without the application crashing. Even the try-catch block doesn't work.
Thanks!

I prevented the crash by using axios and writeAsStringAsync instead of downloadAsync.
    const download = async (uriHttps, uriFile, useAxiosWorkaround = true) => {
        if (useAxiosWorkaround) {
            const response = await axios.get(uriHttps, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
            const base64 = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
            await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uriFile, base64, {encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64});
            return;
        }

        // TODO: fix crash!!
        await FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(uriHttps, uriFile).downloadAsync();
    };

